# can reset parameterized SQL?

Tags: java, sql, parameterized-query

I'm new to **Parameterized SQL**, What I'm about doing is updating stuff with it, It's fine there, But i have a (log) table that holds that Parameterized SQL as Description of what happened, When i insert Parameterized SQL to `log_table`
it keeps showing "?" this symbol

code to save log:

```
    PreparedStatement stat;
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql="insert into rozhanai_log values (null,?,?,?)";
    try
    {
        stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1,sqlParadanan);//(sqlParadanan) is my parameterized SQL String
        stat.setTimestamp(2,time);
        stat.setString(3,empName);
        stat.execute();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("log Nabw");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and SQL String in (log) table shown like this:

```
update rozhanai_customer_account set rozhanai_money_balance = rozhanai_money_balance + 1000.0 where rozhanai_account_id=?
```

what can i do here?

i was thinking about something like (re-set the parameters)?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it will always show `?` for the parameters. Remember that JDBC does not "concatenate" the parameters as string values into the PreparedStatement. It performs a direct insertion of the value(s) in the database engine session according to the JDBC type. For example, `setTimestamp()` will send a bona fide timestamp value, not its string representation.

Comment: I would suggest rendering values themselves into strings and saving these strings instead of the SQL statement. Maybe in a CSV-like format.

Comment: @TheImpaler: that's not true for the Postgres JDBC driver. `PreparedStatement.toString()` will actually show the parameter values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this method works fine, thanks!

Comment: @mhamadarsalan If it worked, please post it as an answer. It could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784439/can-reset-parameterized-sql?noredirect=1#comment92496003_52784439) for helping, simply with `PreparedStatement.toString()` can get SQL String without any `?` symbol

```
    .
    .
    stat.setString(3,empName);
    String fullSQL = stat.toString();
    System.out.println(fullSQL); 
    .
    .
    .
```

> **output :**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6b179d: insert into rozhanai_log values (null,update rozhanai_customer...,2018-05-23,'Hama')
```

thanks for you

Comment: sorry for that, his account link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)